# SQL / MySQL related questions - where to guide them?

Tags: discussion

I just ran over a question that was basically asking about MySQL and collation. I would say it's not within the scope of the wodpress answers site (but kindly answered it anyway, these points get me addicted ;) ).

So I'm just asking myself to which SE site to guide for explicit MySQL related "how to write a SQL query properly" questions? Excerpt from the dropdown list:

- Super User
- Stack Overflow (I think this one)
- Programmers
- Server Fault
- Webmasters

Any kind of feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends entirely on the context of the question -- if it's about MySQL *in the context of specific WordPress queries* then it belongs here.

If it is a general question about writing MySQL queries that has little or nothing to do with WordPress, then it probably belongs elsewhere.

In other words, how wordpress-y is the question?

Comment: [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/default-table-collation-on-plugin-activation/5937). Some question are about working with WP APIs to build and run queries - obviously they do belong. This one is mostly running raw SQL query and issue in question (collation) is about MySQL and not WordPress mechanics.

Comment: @Rarst: Thanks for linking the question, it's the one.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question does belong on WPSE, since it refers to creating tables with the correct charset and collation *from a plugin*. Reading your article makes me think that using the `$wpdb->charset` and `$wpdb->collate` options are important, and not just `utf8`, because others might use a different setting for a reason.

If I would refer someone to get more specific SQL help, I think Stack Overflow is always a good place. In theory Server Fault should be the place for server-related questions (and thus MySQL-specific stuff, like how to set a collation), but in practice SO also covers this. Super User is for individual PCs you physically work on, not servers. Webmasters seems to be a higher level site, mostly about SEO and information architecture, and Programmers is about everything but the code.

Answer (score 1):

My view it that **if it mentions the use of a WordPress plugin or a theme them it is an okay question** for this site.

To me [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/default-table-collation-on-plugin-activation/5937) is fine for WordPress Answers. While the guy might get a faster answer on SO I'm very happy to see it here on WA because:

1. It's a question I needed to know the answer to for my WordPress work, but didn't, and
2. Lots of WordPress developers need to know the answer too.

So if a question makes no mention of WordPress at all then I've ask the comment *"How does this related to WordPress"* but if it is a question about SQL in any context of WordPress then I think it is fair game here and my vote is I want those questions here.  FWIW.

-Mike